# How to mutate multiple variables with the same prefix all at once

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to apply a function to mutate multiple variables starting with the same prefix into other variables also starting with the same prefix. It works with the code below, but I would like to know if there is a shorter code that would do the same. Thanks!

```
fctdmat01 <- function(x) {factor(cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 2.65, +Inf), labels = c("no", "yes")))}

deppar <-  mutate(deppar, 
              dmat01.1 = fctdmat01(dmat.1),
              dmat01.2 = fctdmat01(dmat.2),
              dmat01.4 = fctdmat01(dmat.4),
              dmat01.6 = fctdmat01(dmat.6),
              dmat01.8 = fctdmat01(dmat.8),
              dmat01.10 = fctdmat01(dmat.10),
              dmat01.12 = fctdmat01(dmat.12),
              dmat01.14 = fctdmat01(dmat.14))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `dplyr`'s `across` function:

```r
library(dplyr)

deppar %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("dmat"), 
                ~fctdmat01(.x),
                .names = "{str_c('dmat01', str_extract(.col, '.[0-9]+'))}"))
```

Comment: Thank you Martin. This code works to transform all my variables starting with "dmat". But the outcome I would like is to keep variables starting with "dmat" as they are, but add to my dataset a group of new variables starting with "dmat01". Those are longitudinal variables, so for each time point, I would like to have the original continuous "dmat" variable and a dichotomised version "dmat01", ending with .1 / .2 / .4 etc. Is it possible to do that with dplyr?

Comment: You could try this: iris example:  `df <- head(iris, 5) df %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with("Sepal"), ~fctdmat01(.x), 
                  .names ="dmat01_{.col}"`.

Comment: Adjusted the answer thanks to TarJae's comment.

Answer (score 2):

An option in `base R`

```
nm1 <- grep("^dmat", names(deppar), value = TRUE)
deppar[nm1] <- lapply(deppar[nm1], fctdmat01)
```